# Is there any difference between ViewStub and View?

Tags: performance, android-view, android-memory, viewstub

I am new to Android Development.
I read about ViewStub from https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/loading-ondemand.html

It mentions that it is cheap and less memory to use it.

I have the following:

MainLayout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Layout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

.....

.....

<Button android:id="@+id/ShowBackground"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

<Button android:id="@+id/ShowBackground2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="@string/title_close" />

<View
  android:id="@+id/ShowView"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
  android:background="@color/blue" />

<ViewStub
    android:id="@+id/ShowViewStub"
    android:layout="@layout/test"        
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ShowViewLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/blue_dimmer"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
    private ViewStub mViewStub;
    private View mView;
    private Button mBackground1;    
    private Button mBackground2
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.MainLayout);

        mView = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.ShowView);
        mViewStub = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.ShowViewStub);
        mBackground1 = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.ShowBackground);

    mBackground1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
         mView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       }
    });
   }

    mBackground2 = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id. ShowBackground2);
    mBackground2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
         mViewStub.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       }
    });
   }
```

Questions:

View and ViewStub are working fine in the MainActivity.

I do understand ViewStub is good for the view that is rarely used.
If ViewStub is called at least 1 time in the MainActivity, shouldn't it be more memory usage since the test.xml layout is added to the activity?

As I can see is that ViewStub is always visible unless it is called View.Gone....

Can someone please explain what the differences between the two?

I greatly appreciate for your help,

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The < include /> will just include the xml contents in your base xml file as if the whole thing was just a single big file. It's a nice way to share layout parts between different layouts.

The < ViewStub /> is a bit different because it is not directly included, and will be loaded only when you actually use it/need it, ie, when you set its visibility to VISIBLE (actually visible) or INVISIBLE (still not visible, but its size isn't 0 anymore). This a nice optimization because you could have a complex layout with tons of small views or headers anywhere, and still have your Activity load up really fast. Once you use one of those views, it'll be loaded.

Comment: thanks for the answer.  I still don't fully understand it.  You said once I use one of the views, it'll be loaded.  Going back to the my question that I mentioned that if I use mView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); once, the test.xml layout will be added to the Activity, wouldn't this be more memory usage since text.xml has been added and is always still in the Activity?  Thanks

Comment: What if I use ViewStub to show the flash white background color everytime I take a picture with Camera app,  is it better or the same than using View?